# Is it possible to apply CSS3 filters to an image, then download the image?

Tags: image, css

Similar to this question: [Capture/save/export an image with CSS filter effects applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270897/capture-save-export-an-image-with-css-filter-effects-applied)

I want to apply CSS3 Filters then let the user download the image with the filters applied. Any way to do this?

Comment: You say similar... What's the difference? Wording is a bit different, but it's basically the same question. Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture/save/export an image with CSS filter effects applied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270897/capture-save-export-an-image-with-css-filter-effects-applied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to convert the pic to base64 after the filter applied using javascript and then let the user download it.